# How to enable textbox when one of the radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 `radio buttons` and a `textbox` in html page using bootstrap 3,i want to make the `textbox` disabled by default and enable it when the radio button `EnterRange` is enabled.Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".radioBtn").click(function() {
    $("#dist").attr("disabled", true);
        if ($("input[name=optradio]:checked").val() == "EnterRange") {
            $("#txtbox").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

html code:

```
<div class="customradio">
    <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" id="5" name="optradio" value="5" checked="checked">
    <label for="5">5 Km</label>
</div>
<div class="customradio">
    <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" id="10" name="optradio" value="10">
    <label for="10">10 Km</label>
</div>
<div class="customradio">
    <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" id="15" name="optradio" value="15">
    <label for="15">15 Km</label>
</div>
<div class="customradio">
    <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" id="EnterRange" name="optradio" value="EnterRange">
    <label for="EnterRange">Enter Range</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" id="dist" name="txtbox" disabled="disabled"> <label>Km</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It is expected that you attempt to solve the problem yourself and then post a question when you get stuck with a specific problem with your code.  Please ake a tour of the help center to see what sort of questions are on topic for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one mistake is here

```
if ($("input[name=optradio]:checked").val() == "EnterRange") {
 $("#dist").attr("disabled", false);  //selector is wrong.
}
```

You have just put `name` as `selector` actually your code is perfect you need to change only this `selector` as  `$("#txtbox")` to `$("#dist")`

```
$(".radioBtn").change(function() {
    $("#dist").attr("disabled", true);
    alert($("input[name=optradio]:checked").val())
        if ($("input[name=optradio]:checked").val() == "EnterRange") {
            $("#dist").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot...it works now...it was my fault..i put the javascript in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by jQuery. Try the following snippets:

Html:

```
<div class="customradio">
    <input class="radioBtn" type="radio" id="EnterRange" name="optradio" value="EnterRange">
    <label for="EnterRange">Enter Range</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" id="dist" name="txtbox"> <label>Km</label>
</div>
```

**for jQuery 1.6+**, You can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dist").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#EnterRange").click(function () {
            $("#dist").prop('disabled', false);
        });
});
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**, The [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) and [`.remoceAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) do the same thing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dist").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#EnterRange").click(function () {
        $("#dist").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: Anything wrong with this solution? So let me know why you push downvote button...!

Comment: Not me who push the down vote button :)....regarding your reply i want it to enable or disable the textbox not  to hide it.

Comment: So you can use `$("#dist").attr('disabled','disabled');` instead of the `$("dist).hide()` and then change `$("#dist").show();` to `$("#dist").removeAttr('disabled');` @Newdeveloper

Comment: I edited the reply just a minute ago :)  @Newdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine just check ID you are using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".radioBtn").click(function() {
    $("#dist").attr("disabled", true);
        if ($("input[name=optradio]:checked").val() == "EnterRange") {
            $("#txtbox").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".radioBtn").click(function() {
    $("#dist").attr("disabled", true);
        if ($("input[name=optradio]:checked").val() == "EnterRange") {
            $("#dist").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot...it works now...it was my fault..i put the javascript in wrong place.